# How to search a string inside a HYPERLINK in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a HYPERLINK in cell A1 which has "Click here" as the Text to Display and "www.websitenamexyz.com" as the actual reference.
I want to search for the text "xyz" in the part "www.websitenamexyz.com". How do I do that because it only searches in the text "Click here". 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it an *Inserted Hyperlink* or an `=HYPERLINK()` formula ???

Comment: Inserted hyperlink.

Comment: You have to use VBA to modify the hyperlinks.